# How to install iOS app to any device without App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, app-store

It's mid 2015 and I've found a lot of old links regarding this problem so I wanted to post a new question. I was wondering how to install generated app to any iPhone/iPad device without publishing it in the App Store?

So, I would like to do the same as I can do with the Android apps. I would like to give my app to close to 1000 selected users so they can use it. For Android I can just take debug apk file and send them to their email and they would be able to install it.

I've found this but it's not for free: http://hockeyapp.net/features

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`TestFlight` Testing makes it easy to invite users to test your `iOS 8` apps before you release them on the `App Store`. You can invite up to 1,000 external testers using just their email address.

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

#### Update

Now you can test your `iOS`, `watchOS`, and `tvOS` and you can invite up to 2,000 testers using email address.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible yet, At least in a pretty way, I mean, if the device in which you will install your app is not jail-broken you will need to sign your app, and if you sign your app it makes no sense not publish it on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The number is unlimited if your iOS device owners all enroll themselves in Apple's $99 Developer program, have recent Macs, and you are willing to distribute a build-able Xcode project to them.  The limit seems to be up to 100 devices if you alone are the only one to enroll, and don't use TestFlight.

Just enroll in Apple's $99 Developer program, add the devices (up to 100) to your provisioning profile in Apple's Developer portal, download the profile to Xcode, then build the app, connect the device to the Mac (or use Ad Hoc provisioning), and install the app.  Or get Apple to approve your app for TestFlight distribution.

If you are doing this for a corporation with a D&B number, then another alternative is to enroll in Apple's more expensive Enterprise program, which allows you to install your app on any employee iOS device, even if this number is well over 100.